# A trigger for Google Analytics add on has run?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the Google Analytics add on for sheets in conjunction with an App Script.

I would like a trigger for when someone uses the add on to run a report (and thus have updated data).

I was looking at the documentation at doPost() and doGet(). Gave it a try and those don;t seem to do the trick.

Is there a logical way to trigger a script in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the report to be run anytime someone opens the add-on you could try the onOpen(e) trigger.  This runs anytime it gets opened, but what you can do with the trigger varies depending on the permissions available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jonathan. Can you expand on that? How exactly would onOpen(e) know that this particular add on had been run?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply @DougFirr.  The onOpen(e) function is called any time a document/spreadsheet with the add-on installed is opened.  If instead you only wanted to trigger the add-on every time the is actually used, and not just opened, you could add a function call to the beginning of the function that generates the report.

Comment: INteresting. Thanks for the info. Can I ask where you learned/read about this?

Comment: The official google apps script reference and guides are where I learnt almost everything I know about apps script.  This [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) is a page with some more info on triggers if you would like to look more into them.  The reference tab has info on all the available apis.  They did a really good job of making it approachable and easy to read.